# Playing Youtube video in kaltura Player

Tags: youtube, kaltura

I am trying to play youtube video by its URL in KDP Kaltura Dynamic Player. Is there any way to Play youtube videos in KDP? The whole purpose is to integrate youtube with Kaltura Player.

Answer (score 0):

You can, Try this.

```
<iframe id="pid_kaltura_player" 
    kentryid="1_j4ipv6ln" 
    kuiconfid="25505291" 
    kwidgetid="_1645161" 
    kpartnerid="1645161" 
    preload="none" width="100%" height="100%" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/81XmhlLJhFg?controls=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;showinfo=0&amp;widget_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fplayer.kaltura.com%2Fmodules%2FExternalPlayers%2Ftests%2FkWidgetYouTubePlayerIframe.html&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fplayer.kaltura.com&amp;widgetid=1">
</iframe>
```

Look here for more, **http://player.kaltura.com/modules/ExternalPlayers/tests/kWidgetYouTubePlayerIframe.html**